# How to create a "blacklist" in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, list, blacklist

I'm making an application in PHP in which employers can accept or reject offers from workers. If you click on the reject button, a function will be called with the id of the offer you want to reject. Now here's my problem, I don't know how to manage those decisions; I have thought maybe making a table to assign the rejecting offer id to the employer email but that would cause a big unordered and difficult to handle table.

I have also thought about making a new field in the employer row, an array, in which I'll store all rejected offers, and another field for the accepted ones of course. What do you think would be a good option? (Doesn't have to be one of this I named)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: You need a normalized schema.  An array of offer IDs violates that principle.  Design a normalized schema and see how it performs.

Comment: Can we see your schema as it stands, edited into your question please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the relationships: An Employee can receive many Offers, and an Offer can be sent to many Employees.  It's a many-to-many relationship.  You need a join table.  It has a primary key that is the composite of the Employee and Offer primary keys.  Each one is a foreign key relationship to the table it came from.

There might be other attributes associated with each row in that join table: a creation timestamp, a flag indicated if it was accepted or rejected, and the acceptance timestamp.

These are fundamentals of relational databases.  You can't design an application well without understanding them.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column on the offersTable with the employerId and one for the accepted|declined as a short integer.